# Error non described on a VBA filtering code

Tags: excel, vba, date, filtering

So, I have this piece of code which should allow me to filter the G Column (Dates) and show only the date of the previous day (If today is October 13th, then only October 12th should appear).

My issue is that the code effectively applies the filter, but does not show results even though the October 12th value is indeed in the column.

This is a screenshot of the result:
[Filtered, but no results shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46CmY.png)

This is my code. When I download this information from SAP, the dates have dots instead of slashes, so I perform a replace on them (from 01.01.2020 to 01/01/2020 for example):
Range("A1").Select

```
Columns("G:G").Select

Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic, Criteria1:=xlFilterYesterday
```

I hope you guys can help me out on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Convert 'Date' Strings to Date

- You'll be better off by converting the strings to 'real' dates. Here's an example of how you could do it.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub convertStringsToDate()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const ColumnIndex As Variant = "G"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Turn off AutoFilter.
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Define Column Range.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColumnIndex).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, ColumnIndex), _
                       ws.Cells(LastRow, ColumnIndex))
    
    ' Write values from Column Range to Data Array.
    Dim Data As Variant
    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Data = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    
    ' Convert values in Data Array, converted to strings, to dates.
    Dim CurrentValue As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        CurrentValue = DotToSlashDate(CStr(Data(i, 1)))
        If Not IsEmpty(CurrentValue) Then
            Data(i, 1) = CurrentValue
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Write dates from Data Array to Column Range.
    rng.Value = Data
    
    ' Apply AutoFilter.
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, _
                              Operator:=xlFilterDynamic, _
                              Criteria1:=xlFilterYesterday

End Sub

' Converts a string in the format of either d.m.yyyy or d.m.yyyy.
' to a date in the current Excel date format.
' If the string is not in the required format, it returns empty.
Function DotToSlashDate(DotDate As String) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ProcExit
    Dim fDot As Long
    fDot = InStr(1, DotDate, ".")
    Dim dDay As String
    dDay = Left(DotDate, fDot - 1)
    Dim sDot As Long
    sDot = InStr(fDot + 1, DotDate, ".")
    Dim mMonth As String
    mMonth = Mid(DotDate, fDot + 1, sDot - fDot - 1)
    Dim yYear As String
    yYear = Replace(Right(DotDate, Len(DotDate) - sDot), ".", "")
    DotToSlashDate = DateSerial(CLng(yYear), CLng(mMonth), CLng(dDay))
ProcExit:
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick question:

As I have my macro stored in Personal, should I replace: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName) with something else?

The code breaks right there for the time being.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing this code, so it is your personal workbook. So either change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook` or you better qualify the workbook like this: `Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsm")`.

Comment: Once again thanks. This worked perfectly. If you have a blog or a page where you talk about Excel, please let me know the name. I would gladly  check it out as I am on the early stages of learning.